# How to get the last object present inside an array of an object in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is the structure of the document of the collection "conversations".

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5549ec1575bd899c17ec5163"),
        "messages" : [
                {
                        "subject" : "From fb to techniche",
                        "from" : ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5549ec1575bd899c17ec5164"),
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-05-06T10:25:25.871Z"),
                        "read" : true,
                        "message" : "Message from fb to techniche",
                        "participants" : [
                                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292")
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "subject" : "diohvoidso",
                        "from" : ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5549f42c75bd899c17ec5165"),
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-05-06T10:59:56.665Z"),
                        "read" : true,
                        "message" : "icdo ovdw iovhiwiohovhoihreiobv",
                        "participants" : [
                                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"),
                         ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "subject" : "some reply subject",
                        "from" : ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5549f76275bd899c17ec5166"),
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-05-06T11:13:38.161Z"),
                        "read" : true,
                        "message" : "this is the body of the latest message",
                        "participants" : [
                                ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b"),

                        ]
                }
        ],
        "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"), // logged in user
                ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
        ],
        "__v" : 10
}
```

I want to get the last object from the messages array which has 'looged-in user' id in the participants array and the logged in user has to present in the outer participants array of the object.

If the loggedin user id is "5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292", then I want the following result.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5549ec1575bd899c17ec5163"),
        "messages" : [
                 {
                        "subject" : "diohvoidso",
                        "from" : ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b"),
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5549f42c75bd899c17ec5165"),
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-05-06T10:59:56.665Z"),
                        "read" : true,
                        "message" : "icdo ovdw iovhiwiohovhoihreiobv",
                        "participants" : [
                                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"),
                         ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"), // logged in user
                ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
        ],
        "__v" : 10
}
```

I need to do the same for all the objects in the collection "conversations" & also I want to populate "from" field & participant fields
I tried the follwing code,but it is not working properly.

```
Conversation.find(
    {
        participants: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id),         
        'messages.participants': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id)
    }, 
    {
        messages: {$slice: -1}
    }
).sort({created: 1, messages: -1})
 .populate({path: 'participants'})
 .populate({path: 'messages.from'})
 .populate('messages.participants', 'displayName')
 .exec(function (err, conversations) {


 });
```

Please help me to get the desired result as follows.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5549ec1575bd899c17ec5163"),
        "messages" : [
                 {
                        "subject" : "diohvoidso",
                        "from" : ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b"), //populated
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5549f42c75bd899c17ec5165"),
                        "created" : ISODate("2015-05-06T10:59:56.665Z"),
                        "read" : true,
                        "message" : "icdo ovdw iovhiwiohovhoihreiobv",
                        "participants" : [
                                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"),// populated
                         ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
                        ]
                }

        ],
        "participants" : [
                ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"), // logged in user
                ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
        ],
        "__v" : 10
}
```

Comment: you need to find out `participants` array presents in `messages.participants` right?

Comment: The logged in user id has to be present in both participants array and messages.participants array & I want the last object

Comment: here some confusion you want only those messages whose `participants` array equals `messages.participants` like this `participants.array = messages.participants.array` and which last object you want ?

Comment: not like that @yogesh .
@ first we have to search for participants array whether it contains logged in user id or not. If it contains , then search for messages.participants array,whether it contains logged in user id or not.
In the messages.participants array among the matched objects , I want the last object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to check `participants` array having value, If yes then you want to search `req.user.id` in both `participants` and `messages.participants` if id presents then sort `messages` array with `created` date and pick latest first `message`.

For this check below aggregation query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$match": { //check participants array not empty 
    "participants": {
      "$not": {
        "$size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  "$unwind": "$messages"
}, {
  "$sort": { // sort messages by created date so latest messages first come 
    "messages.created": -1
  }
}, {
  "$match": {
    "messages.participants": ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292"),
    "participants": ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292")
  }
}, {
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "messages": { // use $first to get latest message info
      "$first": "$messages"
    },
    "participants": {
      "$first": "$participants"
    },
    "__v": {
      "$first": "$__v"
    }
  }
}).pretty()
```

Or If you know all `participants` array in advance then you should try this `elemMatch` also

```
db.collectionName.find({
    "participants": ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292")
    , "participants": ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
    , "messages": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "participants": ObjectId("5530b6208ab0478c2bd23292")
      }
    }
    , "messages": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "participants": ObjectId("5534a588a12ae5ac11dc6f6b")
      }
    }
  }, {
    "messages.$.participants": 1
  })
  .pretty()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yogesh :)  But however it has not solved my problem. I want to populate the 'from' & 'participants' field. All I want is to check whether the logged in user is present in the outer 'participants' array & if so , check for 'messages.participants' array for the same. Now we have the object with 'messages' array containing message objects. Now I want the latest message object of the 'messages.participants' array with 'from','participants' fields populated. Please see the query I have tried :)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg : I have edited the question. Please see the desired output at the end, also help me to get the same. Thanks